# .net core 2.2--Bot Authentication Error --- returned an invalid status code ‘ProxyAuthenticationRequired’

Tags: .net, .net-core, botframework

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth) to authenticate users.

While testing this on Bot Emulator my code(pasted below) is throwing error  ---Operation returned an invalid status code ‘ProxyAuthenticationRequired’

```
Operation returned an invalid status code ‘ProxyAuthenticationRequired’ at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.UserToken.GetTokenWithHttpMessagesAsync(String userId, String connectionName, String channelId, String code, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\UserToken.cs:line 90

at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.UserTokenExtensions.GetTokenAsync(IUserToken operations, String userId, String connectionName, String channelId, String code, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\UserTokenExtensions.cs:line 40

at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.GetUserTokenAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String connectionName, String magicCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 583

at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt.GetUserTokenAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\Prompts\OAuthPrompt.cs:line 204

at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\Prompts\OAuthPrompt.cs:line 110

at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 113
```

Here is the code

```
public myBotDialog(
           BotServices botServices,
           UserState userState,
           IConfiguration config,
           ISearchService searchService,
           IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient)
           : base(nameof(myBotDialog))
        {
            _accessor = userState.CreateProperty<SearchState>(nameof(SearchState));
            InitialDialogId = nameof(BeginSearchDialog);
            _config = config;
            _searchService = searchService;
            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
                nameof(OAuthPrompt),
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = "abcbotauthconnection",
                    Text = "Please Sign In",
                    Title = "Sign In",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
                }));
            var onboarding = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptStepAsync,
                LoginStepAsync,
              AskForSearchText,
              ProcessResultsAsync,
              FinishSearchDialog,
            };

            // To capture built-in waterfall dialog telemetry, set the telemetry client
            // to the new waterfall dialog and add it to the component dialog
            TelemetryClient = telemetryClient;
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialDialogId, onboarding) { TelemetryClient = telemetryClient });
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(DialogIds.SearchTextPrompt));
            //AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(DialogIds.SearchResult, new WaterfallStep[] { ProcessResultsAsync }));

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

         //exception error at this line
          return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);

  }



private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
            // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to view your token?") }, cancellationToken);
            }

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

Question.
Does anyone know how to fix this!?
**Where to setup my proxy information in this scenario?**

I deployed this to azure, then tried to test in webchat, but getting error "[File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth']"

Note: **I am using .net core2.2, Bot framework SDK 4 and Virtual Assistant template**

Comment: Are you using your bot behind a closed network?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes Yes inside corporate network

Comment: What channel or is this the emulator?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes bot emulator

Comment: @roney what version of the bot framework SDK are you using? Also, you stated that you deployed this on azure, by any chance is your code running locally or everything is on the cloud?